# Programming model when looking for when multiple callbacks are done

Tags: javascript, orm, callback, coffeescript

I have loop through some items that are coming back from the database.  I don't want to send the items to the rendering engine until I have all the data.  What I don't know how to do is to know when I have all the elements

```
data = {}
pizza.toppings (err, toppings)->
    for topping in toppings
        topping.flavors (err, flavors)->
            data[topping.name] = flavors.length

    return data
```

Anywhere I put the return data, it will alwyas get returned instantly.  Is there a way to structure this code so that `data` is only returned when all the callbacks have completed?

Comment: no, you can't stall the return, but you can move the action needing the data into the callback.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like an async library. Have a look at this one: https://github.com/caolan/async
They have several ControlFlow functions which hopefully match your UseCase.
Alternatively you can use Promises too.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {}
pizza.toppings (err, toppings) ->
  _toppingLength = toopings.length
  doSomethingFinally = ->
    if _toppingLength is data.length
      console.log("done!!")
  for topping in toppings
    topping.flavors (err, flavors) ->
      data[topping.name] = flavors.length
      doSomethingFinally()
```

need words?